# C++ console insert text without overwriting

Tags: c++, console, command-line-interface, ascii, cout

I have a C++ function to be called by some thread; the function inserts a line of text (using [ANSI](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt)) into the console, without abrupting current user input.

This works fine until the bottom of the console is reached, where the user input gets overwritten, since the console is not auto-scrolling, like so:

[image: Screenshot of CLI error.]

The code:

```cpp
void log_insert(std::string& line)
{
    static int num_of_lines = 1;

    // save horizontal cursor position
    std::cout << "\033[s";

    // insert <X> number of lines (\033[<X>L)
    std::cout << "\033[" << num_of_lines + 1 << "L";

    // move cursor to beginning
    std::cout << "\033[G";

    // print text
    std::cout << line << "\n";

    // restore horizontal cursor position
    std::cout << "\033[u";

    // move down <X> number of lines
    std::cout << "\033[" << num_of_lines + 1 << "B";
}
```

I know there are libraries out there for CLI's, but I figured this would be a pretty simple thing to fix. I have tried using ANSI scroll, but without any luck.

Comment: c++ doesn't have any notion of console teminal controlling. How and at which extend you can interact ith a specific console terminal program, completely depends on the latter.

Comment: I get that; but I was wondering whether I could somehow keep the "input line" in focus using the ANSI escape codes.

Comment: There's no standardized behavior doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You would solve your problem by setting the console cursor to the beginning by using this method:

```cpp
void setCursor(int x, int y) {
    HANDLE hOut;
    COORD position;

    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    position.X = x;
    position.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, position);
}
```